# Switching to Lodash from Underscore

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, marionette, lodash

I just started supporting a huge Backbone and Marionette application. Currently using Underscore and the version is 1.7.0.

I would like to switch to `Lodash` latest version to take advantage of new features like the one I learned today from my other post, _.has()'s deep search. Also I'm using `RequireJS`

What is the safest way to switch to `Lodash`? Do I

```
1. bower install lodash
2. update require.confg

    "underscore": "../components/underscore/underscore",
    "underscore.string": "../components/underscore.string/lib/underscore.string",

    and update the values to point to `lodash` paths but keep the property names?
```

Here is one example that may or may not work with Lodash. It's just an example.

```
convertModels: function convertModels() {
  _.each(this.models, _.bind(function (model) {
    model = this.convertItem(model);
  }, this));
},
```

This post is also about "will I need to change some of the Underscore codes" or will Lodash be able to handle and produce the same output. Or I will just need to check the application and see what happens?

Comment: It's sad that I got deducted from this post since my grammar was bad. I did my best especially english isn't my native language. The changes were minor though. The "Backbone/Marionette" according to the editor was bad. It got changed to "Backbone/ Marionette" but I decided to write it as "Backbone and Marionette" which is better :(

Comment: The reason for the down vote is likely because this isn't a programming problem. There was also a lot of other stuff that needed trimming.

Comment: Thank you. I'll be more careful next time. I'll edit the post and add a code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

faced same task some time ago and did this via require config:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        // ..
        "lodash": "libs/lodash-3.9.3",
        "backbone": "libs/backbone-1.2.0",
        // ..
    },
    map: {
        "*": {
            // use lodash instead of underscore
            "underscore": "lodash"
        }
    }
}
```

..details here: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-map
I use _ functions a lot and didn't have to change anything after the switch.

Comment: I made something similar and it worked! Though your config looks cooler. I've never used map. What is map for?

Comment: Well, you can for example  replace underscore with lodash without having to change backbone source..:) Check the link I have added for details..